# Optimize png files with grunt-img

Tags: javascript, png, gruntjs

I'm trying to do a grunt task to optimize my png project files. I'm using grunt-img plugin and this is my grunt.initConfig:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        img: {
            task1: {
                src: ['myapp/Skins/**/*.png'],
                dest: 'myapp/img-temp'
            }
        }
    });
```

That should do, process all png files in Skins folders, compress and put them into img-temp folder, right? Right.
First, i had an error because jpegtran isn't installed on my computer (woh, i put *.png why did it needs jpegtran?) but ok, i installed it and try again. And now i have this error:

```
Running "img:task1" (img) task
Running optipng... app/Skins/skin1/img/navigationBar/background.png, app/Skins/skin1/img/navigationBar/nb_buttons.png, ...
>> 1
** Error: Unrecognized option: -clobber
```

Anybody knows what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find what it means, but i find that grunt-img is deprecated, now we have [grunt-contrib-imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin)

It works!